# Initialize array interface

Tags: typescript

As said in the [Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#array-types), you can declare a custom array interface with string or number index:

```
interface StringArray {
    [index: number]: string;
}
```

So I made this:

```
interface EventRegistrations {
    [index:string]:ListenerEntry[];
}
```

problem is simple: how can I initialize such a thing?

Here is what I tried and the error message provided (using PhpStorm 2016.1 with tsc 1.8.7):

```
foo:EventRegistrations = [];
```

> Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'EventRegistrations'

```
foo:EventRegistrations = [[]];
```

> Type 'undefined[][]' is not assignable to type 'EventRegistrations'

```
foo:EventRegistrations = [index:string]:ListenerEntry[];
```

> Syntax error (expected , where first : is)

```
foo:EventRegistrations = [string]:ListenerEntry[];
```

> Syntax error (expected ; where : is)

```
foo:EventRegistrations = new EventRegistrations();
```

> Syntax error (cannot find name 'EventRegistrations')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you are not actually defining an array `[]`, you are defining a dictionary `{}`, since string indexers are used for dictionary style lookup.

In the following example, you will see that the object is declared using `{}` rather than `[]`, because in JavaScript, all objects are dictionaries *(even arrays!)* Arrays just have special semantics and a `length` property that allows them to behave like arrays *(numerically indexed)*

```
interface ListenerEntry {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

interface EventRegistrations {
    [index:string]:ListenerEntry[];
}

var x: EventRegistrations = {};

x["one"][0].foo = "Hello";
x["two"][1].bar = "World";
```